# How to develop previous and next buttons in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button

I am new to React and I am having a hard time trying to come up with code to make my buttons perform what I want. I want them to cycle through the array that they are given and display different information each time. I have tried for loop and forEach method and have tried adding the item to itself but nothing seems to work. I have tried to read the documentation on React but it gives me nothing. I don't know if there is a specific way to do it in React, can someone point me in the right direction?

Here is my code:

```
class Members extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userInput: null,
      senators: [],
      represenatives: [],
      bills: [],
      
    }
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      userInput: e.target.value.toUpperCase()
    })
  }

  right = (i) => {
    i.forEach(element => {
      element = element++
      console.log(element)
    });

  }
  left = (i) => {

    console.log(i.id)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const key = `xCaHBd8gI5ZJSOUXWFJGOXZBjJtMbvoIcip0kSmS`
    const urls = [`https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/116/senate/members.json`,
      `https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/102/house/members.json`,
      `https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/statements/latest.json`,
      `https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/bills/search.json`];

    let requests = urls.map(url => fetch(url, {
      type: "GET",
      dataType: 'json',
      headers: {
        'X-API-Key': key
      }
    }))
    Promise.all(requests)
      .then(res => {
        return Promise.all(res.map(res => res.json()));
      }).then(response => {
        this.setState({
          senators: response[0].results[0].members,
          represenatives: response[1].results[0].members,
          bills: response[2].results
        })
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })

  }

  render() {

    const { senators, bills, represenatives, userInput } = this.state;


    const inSenate = senators.filter(
      (senator) => senator.state === userInput
    )

    const inHouse = represenatives.filter(
      (represenative) => represenative.state === userInput
    )

    const draft = bills.find(
      (bill) => bill.name === inSenate.last_name)



    return (

      <div className="congress">
        <div className="users">
          <h2>{this.state.userInput}</h2>
          <input className="userInput" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </div>

        {inSenate.map((senate, i) => {
          return (
            <div key={senate.id} className="senate">
              <h2 className="senateName">Senate</h2>
              <ul className="bio">
                <h2 >{senate.short_title + " " + senate.first_name + " " + senate.last_name}</h2>
                <li>{senate.title}</li>
                <li>State: <strong>{senate.state}</strong></li>
                <li>Party: <strong>{senate.party}</strong></li>
                <li>DOB: <strong>{senate.date_of_birth}</strong></li>
                <li>Next Election: <strong>{senate.next_election}</strong></li>
                <li>Missed Votes: <strong>{senate.missed_votes}</strong></li>
                <li> Votes With Party Percentage: <strong>{senate.votes_with_party_pct + "%"}</strong></li>
                <li>Votes Against Party Percentage: <strong>{senate.votes_against_party_pct + "%"}</strong></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          )
        })}

        {inHouse.map((rep, i) => {
          return (
            <div key={rep.id} className="house">
              <h2 className="numbers" >Your state has {inHouse.length} Represenative(s)</h2>
              <h2 >{rep.short_title + " " + rep.first_name + " " + rep.last_name}</h2>
              <ul className="bio">
                <li  >{rep.title}</li>
                <li  >State: <strong>{rep.state}</strong></li>
                <li  >Party: <strong>{rep.party}</strong></li>
                <li  >DOB: <strong>{rep.date_of_birth}</strong></li>
                <li  >Next Election: <strong>{rep.next_election}</strong></li>
                <li  >Missed Votes: <strong>{rep.missed_votes}</strong></li>
                <li  > Votes With Party Percentage: <strong>{rep.votes_with_party_pct + "%"}</strong></li>
                <li  >Votes Against Party Percentage: <strong>{rep.votes_against_party_pct + "%"}</strong></li>
              </ul>
              <button onClick={() => this.left(inHouse)} className="left btn"></button>
              <button onClick={() => this.right(inHouse)} className="right btn"></button>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>

    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details. What do you want exacty to happen. The inHouse map shows all the reps when rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution. It uses states to change the information every time the button is pressed:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, Component } from "react";
import { InputText } from "primereact/inputtext";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userInput: "CA",
      senators: [],
      represenatives: [],
      bills: [],
      repst: 0, //state for changing representative everytime the button is pressed
    };
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      userInput: e.target.value.toUpperCase(),
    });
  };

  right = (i) => {
    if (this.state.repst + 1 < i.length)
      this.setState({
        repst: this.state.repst + 1,
      });
  };
  left = (i) => {
    if (this.state.repst - 1 > -1)
      this.setState({
        repst: this.state.repst - 1,
      });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const key = `xCaHBd8gI5ZJSOUXWFJGOXZBjJtMbvoIcip0kSmS`;
    const urls = [
      `https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/116/senate/members.json`,
      `https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/102/house/members.json`,
      `https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/statements/latest.json`,
      `https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/bills/search.json`,
    ];

    let requests = urls.map((url) =>
      fetch(url, {
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
          "X-API-Key": key,
        },
      })
    );
    Promise.all(requests)
      .then((res) => {
        return Promise.all(res.map((res) => res.json()));
      })
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          senators: response[0].results[0].members,
          represenatives: response[1].results[0].members,
          bills: response[2].results,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { senators, bills, represenatives, userInput } = this.state;

    const inSenate = senators.filter((senator) => senator.state === userInput);

    const inHouse = represenatives.filter(
      (represenative) => represenative.state === userInput
    );

    const draft = bills.find((bill) => bill.name === inSenate.last_name);

    return (
      <div className="congress">
        <div className="users">
          <h2>{this.state.userInput}</h2>
          <input className="userInput" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </div>
        {inSenate.map((senate, i) => {
          return (
            <div key={senate.id} className="senate">
              <h2 className="senateName">Senate</h2>
              <ul className="bio">
                <h2>
                  {senate.short_title +
                    " " +
                    senate.first_name +
                    " " +
                    senate.last_name}
                </h2>
                <li>{senate.title}</li>
                <li>
                  State: <strong>{senate.state}</strong>
                </li>
                <li>
                  Party: <strong>{senate.party}</strong>
                </li>
                <li>
                  DOB: <strong>{senate.date_of_birth}</strong>
                </li>
                <li>
                  Next Election: <strong>{senate.next_election}</strong>
                </li>
                <li>
                  Missed Votes: <strong>{senate.missed_votes}</strong>
                </li>
                <li>
                  {" "}
                  Votes With Party Percentage:{" "}
                  <strong>{senate.votes_with_party_pct + "%"}</strong>
                </li>
                <li>
                  Votes Against Party Percentage:{" "}
                  <strong>{senate.votes_against_party_pct + "%"}</strong>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          );
        })}
        {inHouse[this.state.repst] ? (
          <div key={inHouse[this.state.repst].id} className="house">
            {console.log(inHouse)}
            <h2 className="numbers">
              Your state has {inHouse.length} Represenative(s)
            </h2>
            <h2>
              {inHouse[this.state.repst].short_title +
                " " +
                inHouse[this.state.repst].first_name +
                " " +
                inHouse[this.state.repst].last_name}
            </h2>
            <ul className="bio">
              <li>{inHouse[this.state.repst].title}</li>
              <li>
                State: <strong>{inHouse[this.state.repst].state}</strong>
              </li>
              <li>
                Party: <strong>{inHouse[this.state.repst].party}</strong>
              </li>
              <li>
                DOB: <strong>{inHouse[this.state.repst].date_of_birth}</strong>
              </li>
              <li>
                Next Election:{" "}
                <strong>{inHouse[this.state.repst].next_election}</strong>
              </li>
              <li>
                Missed Votes:{" "}
                <strong>{inHouse[this.state.repst].missed_votes}</strong>
              </li>
              <li>
                {" "}
                Votes With Party Percentage:{" "}
                <strong>
                  {inHouse[this.state.repst].votes_with_party_pct + "%"}
                </strong>
              </li>
              <li>
                Votes Against Party Percentage:{" "}
                <strong>
                  {inHouse[this.state.repst].votes_against_party_pct + "%"}
                </strong>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <button onClick={() => this.left(inHouse)} className="left btn">
              Next
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => this.right(inHouse)} className="right btn">
              Prev
            </button>
          </div>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. It the repst worked when I put it each individually on the elements but it didn't work when I put it on the key. It says they need to be unique. I know your probably sleep, but when you find the time could you walk me through your thought process. I want to know how you came up with the logic, as I have trouble sometimes doing that.

Comment: I will have to see your code to comment on that. But simply put, repst is a state. One of the special property of a state is that it updates values in run time. So we can make changes to it and they will reflect instantaneously in the render. With const, var, let etc you can't do that. That is the logic behind my code.